# casting from FLEX to PHP

Tags: php, apache-flex, amfphp

AS3 code

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- this is the RemoteObject  used to make the RPC calls -->
    <mx:RemoteObject id="myRemote" destination="MyService" source="MyService"
       endpoint="http://localhost/amfphp/gateway.php"                
            showBusyCursor="true"/>

</fx:Declarations>

protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var aut:VOAuthor;  // value object class
    aut = new VOAuthor();
    aut.id_aut = 3;
    aut.fname_aut = "test";
    aut.lname_aut = "123";
    myRemote.saveData(aut);
}
```

Receving PHP code

```
public function saveData($author) 
{
   $mysql = mysql_connect("localhost", "mx112", "xxxxxx");          
   mysql_select_db("flex360");      
   $query = "INSERT INTO authors (fname_aut, lname_aut) VALUES ('".$author->fname_aut."', '".$author->lname_aut."')";          
   $result = mysql_query($query);                 
   return $author;
}


<?php
class VOAuthor {   
 public $id_aut;    
 public $fname_aut;    
 public $lname_aut;        
 var $_explicitType="org.corlan.VOAuthor";}
?>
```

Flex network monitor response : Raw view

```
{lname_aut=123, _explicitType=org.corlan.VOAuthor, fname_aut=test, id_aut=3}
```

but If I do this at the end of the php code

```
 return $author->lname_aut;
```

network monitor response is NULL

so the problem is I can print the array but how to cast tht array to a known php type ?
After 5 days I finnaly figured out flex and mysql using amfphp  any one please help ?

Comment: tx @pkyeck I will try your code by the way I tried this $author['fname_aut'] this worked for me but since I am using a simple example its okay how about complex systems an invoice system I might have to send multiple classes in one remote request How to handle the data in that time ? pls advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using amfphp and Flash you have to register your VOs:

```
import org.corlan.VOAuthor;
// ...
registerClassAlias("org.corlan.VOAuthor", VOAuthor);
```

only then does php recognize the objects you're sending it from ActionScript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to register your class, and an alternative is to use the metadata tag in the Flex VO declaration.

```
package VO
{
    [RemoteClass(alias="org.corlan.VOAuthor")]
    public class VOAuthor
    {
        private var id_aut   : int;
        public var fname_aut : String;
        public var lname_aut : String;
...
```

Hope that helps,

Roger.

PS. A more detailed explanation (that helped me) can be found here: http://www.brentknigge.com/?q=node/499